# New Maven Project in Eclipse IDE J2SE-1.5 issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

When I create a new maven project using m2e plugin, I choose web-app archetype, the default execution environment was set to J2SE-1.5.

I'm running my eclipse with JDK 1.7.0_45

I can change it from J2SE-1.5 to JDK 1.7.0_45 using project's Libraries build path or I can specify the 'maven-compiler-plugin' source and target in pom.xml but these are temp solutions which I don't prefer.
Can I change the default bounded JDK to be 1.7 instead of 1.5.

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

The default being 1.5 is set by maven. So every other programmer that wants to compile your project compiles it as 1.5 project when you don't specify anything else in the pom.xml. The entry in the pom.xml is the way to go here.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add the following to your POM for your new project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your own pom with the preferences you like (i.e. source and target jdk), and make each new project inherit from this pom.